# defining recursive values C

Tags: c, macros

```
 #define BLOCK_OFFSET(block) (BASE_OFFSET+(block-1)*block_size)
```

usage

```
        lseek(fd, BLOCK_OFFSET(group->bg_inode_table)+(inode_no-1)*sizeof(struct ext2_inode),SEEK_SET);
```

This is a fragment of a code im trying to understand and I have no idea how that definition works.
Is it recursive?
Can someone explain step by step whats happening in that lseek?

Comment: What are you thinking is defined recursively? BLOCK_OFFSET and BASE_OFFSET are not the same thing and I see nothing self-referential in the lseek(2) either.

Comment: The define simply replaces BLOCK_OFFSET(foobar) with (BASE_OFFSET+(foobar - 1)*block_size). It's useful to simplify the writing of expressions, but it's not recursive.

Comment: could you explain how can i remove the definition and edit lseek so it works? i just want to know what exactly it does

Comment: You can do it manually. When you find BLOCK_OFFSET(anything), you replace it with (BASE_OFFSET+(anything-1)*block_size). You of course must have block_size defined somewhere, as well as BASE_OFFSET. The latter is probably in some include somewhere. block_size might be a variable, though. **But why would you want to remove the definition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a macro with one parameter. When the pre-processor sees `BLOCK_OFFSET(...)` then it is replaced by `(BASE_OFFSET+(...-1)*block_size)`

```
#define BLOCK_OFFSET(block) (BASE_OFFSET+(block-1)*block_size)
```

The second is a usage of the macro as described above:

Before pre-processing:

```
lseek(fd, BLOCK_OFFSET(group->bg_inode_table)+(inode_no-1)*sizeof(struct ext2_inode),SEEK_SET);
```

After pre-processing:

```
lseek(fd, (BASE_OFFSET+(group->bg_inode_table-1)*block_size)+(inode_no-1)*sizeof(struct ext2_inode),SEEK_SET);
```

If you use gcc you could use `gcc -E file.c` to pre-process the file only and then you could look at the file and verify what the pre-processor did.